# Why acidity of hydrogen hallide increase down the group 17

Tags: acid-base

I just wandering when going down group 17 the electronegativity decreases, and acidity increase with an increase in electronegativity. Then theoritically it should have decrease its acidity of hydrogen hallide when going down the group, but why the result show that the acidity increase down the group instead?

Answer (score 0):

The same happens in group 16, it is actually related to the fact that the hydrogen-halogen bond energy decreases as we go down the group and thus losing H+ ion becomes easier and therefore down the group H+ donating capability increases and so does the acidity.

Comment: So that mean when going down the group, the effect of bond energy overweight the effect of electronegativity ,right?

Comment: We always see bond energy, you might have a case in which electronegativity plays the major role in deciding bond energy but it is not that case here.